# Where does Tomcat cache my taglib .jar files?

Tags: tomcat, cache

I'm deploying a .jar file to a tomcat instance (we're running 6.0.18 on Redhat linux) and according to the log output the old .jar is still being used. I've restarted everthing I can think of, have deleted the work directory etc.etc. but to no avail. I'm no tomcat expert, so here's my question: where should I look for to ascertain if tomcat is using a cached jar and how should I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Stop tomcat, `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop`
2. Delete the work and temp directories, `rm -rf $TOMCAT_HOME/{temp,work}/*`
3. Start tomcat, `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start`